# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'Activation'

Tags: tensorflow, chatbot

I am building a chatbot. While specifying the activation function from keras, I am getting an attribute error as "AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'Activation'"

```
 input_sequence = Input((max_story_len,))
 question = Input((max_question_len,))
 # INPUT ENCODER M
 input_encoder_m = Sequential()
 input_encoder_m.add(Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size, output_dim=64))
 input_encoder_m.add(Dropout(0.3))
 # INPUT ENCODER C
 input_encoder_c = Sequential()
 input_encoder_c.add(Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size, output_dim=max_question_len))
 input_encoder_c.add(Dropout(0.3)) 
 question_encoder = Sequential()
 question_encoder.add(Embedding(input_dim = vocab_size, output_dim=64, 
 input_length=max_question_len))
 question_encoder.add(Dropout(0.3))

 input_encoded_m = input_encoder_m(input_sequence)
 input_encoded_c = input_encoder_c(input_sequence)
 question_encoded = question_encoder(question)
 match =dot([input_encoded_m, question_encoded], axes= (2,2))
 match.Activation('softmax')(match)
```

Comment: My tensorflow version is '2.3.0'

Comment: Maybe you meant `tf.nn.softmax(match)`? Clearly `match` does not have that attribute.